# Полсуток, полпятого

Tags: грамотная-речь

Что делать, если эти слова нужно употребить в других падежах? Правильно ли будет сказать так?

*Уже больше полсуток прошло.*
*Я освобожусь не раньше полпятого.*

Или надо *"полусуток"? "Половина суток"* в этом случае не лучше для разговора?
А вместо *"полпятого"* в моём примере может лучше говорить *"половины пятого"?*

Интересно, что во втором случае я склоняюсь к "половине" (невольно обычно стараюсь так сказать), а в первом случае мне кажется, что с ней звучит уж слишком сложно, тяжело, неестественно для простого разговора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложные имена существительные, первый компонент которых образован числительным пол (половина), типа полчаса, полдюжины, пол-арбуза имеют в косвенных падежах (кроме винительного, совпадающего с именительным) двоякого рода формы: в книжной речи пол меняется на полу, а в разговорной может сохраняться без изменения. Ср.:
а)      от получаса не осталось ни одной минуты; к полудюжине карандашей добавлено еще три; в полуарбузе было три килограмма веса; Я уже более полугода не бывал у них (Аксаков); Учитель невольно остановился на полуслове (Телешов);
б)      растворить лекарство в полстакане воды; ограничиться полдюжиной карандашей; На полслове он обрывал и тер себе лоб... (А. Н. Толстой); Полгодом позже я написал навеянное одной из этих поездок стихотворение... (Симонов); В полверсте, в кустах – противник (Твардовский) (Розенталь Д. Э.)

Comment: Спасибо, Стася!

Answer (score 0):

*Уже больше полсуток прошло* - все верно, полусуток - это более разговорный вариант. Если использовать слово "половина", то правильно сказать *"Уже больше половины суток прошло"*, но не вижу принципиально разницы между изначальной фразой и этой.

*Я освобожусь не раньше полпятого*. - аналогично, можно сказать *"я освобожусь не раньше половины пятого"*, но оба варианта правильные.

Comment: На Грамоте как раз написано, что с У основной вариант, а без У — разговорный.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *На Грамоте как раз написано, что с У основной вариант, а без У — разговорный.* - на сарае тоже написано. Размытая формулировка. Вообще "Грамота" часто дает ответы расплывчатые, и даже когда они правильны, сомнительна возможность применения формулировок за пределами контекста конкретного вопроса.

Comment: По крайней мере Стася это подтверждает.

Comment: http://lopatin.academic.ru/106219/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA - русский орфографический словарь

Comment: @KseniaK, "полусуток" - вариант не разговорный, а более простой фонетически. Все остальные положения нуждаются в более четких формулировках.

Comment: Что, Ксения? У Вас то же самое написано: "полсуток" разговорное, "полусуток" — основной вариант.

Comment: Там написано, что в родительном падеже "полсуток" - разговорный. "Полусуток" - более правильный. Но это все очень условно. Посмотрите в нацкорпусе. Абсолютное превосходство у формы "полсуток" - причем у классиков.

Comment: Кстати, да. Зато в НКРЯ примеров на форму в родительном больше с "полУсуток". Но примеров все равно мало.

Comment: Никто так и не сказал, какие варианты ему ближе.( Вы вот, Ксения, как предпочитаете говорить в случаях моих обеих фраз?

Answer (score 0):

***Полсуток*** - других форм не имеет, в разговорно-просторечном стиле может использоваться во всех падежах в неизменной форме. Нормативно в косвенных падежах заменяется на формы от "полусуток".

***Полусуток*** - Именительного падежа не имеет. Склоняется: И -, Р: "полусуток", Д: - "полусуткам" и т. д.

***Полпятого*** - используется только для обозначения времени, функции наречия. Разговорная форма от половина пятого. Других форм не имеет.

Comment: Меня интересует, как бы вы *скорее* сказали (и другие тоже) в моих примерах. Именно так, как я написал?

Comment: *Меня интересует, как бы вы скорее сказали (и другие тоже) в моих примерах. Именно так, как я написал?* - Я бы сказал "Уже больше полусуток прошло"*.  А другие - наверно да, "полсуток", если судить по нацкорпусу. На "полпятого" вариантов нету. "Половина пятого" - это уже отдельная форма. Правильно, но длинно.

Comment: Спасибо, что про сутки сказали! А насчёт 4:30 или 16:30 (назовём так, чтобы двусмысленности не было) мне и интересно, какую из этих двух форм (полпятого или половина пятого) вы бы предпочли.))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой ну  же третий раз уже сказал. "Полпятого". Нет альтернативы. - "До половины пятого" -  если только есть сомнения, что меня плохо слышат. Но это не другая форма, это другая конструкция, полная.

Comment: Да я не отдельно про "полпятого" говорю, а как в моём примере. "Я освобожусь не раньше полпятого" или "Я освобожусь не раньше половины пятого" вы скажете скорее?

Comment: Ну я вам уже пятый раз говорю: что в вашем варианте, что в любом другом я скажу "полпятого".

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Уже больше полсуток (разг.)  прошло.   Уже больше полусуток (нейтр.)  прошло.

Я освобожусь не раньше полпятого (форма ПОЛУ вообще не используется).

**Пояснение**

1) Корень ПОЛ многозначный. В словаре указано 4 его значения, причем во многих случаях форма ПОЛУ в косвенных падежах вообще не используется (например, нельзя сказать: полстены -  нет полустены). Формы косвенных падежей  существительных с корнем ПОЛ только  **в некоторых случаях** могут быть образованы также с ПОЛУ.

2) Но если в косвенных падежах форма ПОЛУ употребляется, то эта форма является **нейтральной**, а форма ПОЛ - **разговорной**: полсуток (нейтр), род. полсуток (разг.) и полусуток.

Comment: *Уже больше полсуток (разг.) прошло* - "полсуток" Найдено 64 документа, 71 вхождение. "полусуток" Найдено 27 документов, 30 вхождений. - http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-main.html  - Ну и кто из них ***"разг"***?

Comment: Деревня Федоровка неподалеку от Рязани ― то есть это по-российски неподалеку, а на лошадях ехать больше полсуток. [М. А. Осоргин. Свидетель истории (1932). ]Больше полусуток истекло времени с тех пор, как Антипыч прошёл, след его простыл и потом был смыт мелким моросливым дождиком, похожим на росу (М. М. Пришвин. Кладовая солнца (1945). Дипломаты у нас на кораблях неважные, и вот уже больше полусуток морячки никак не могут между собой столковаться (М. С. Бабушкин).

Comment: А у меня всего три примера нашлось (1:2), да и то из старой литературы. Может быть, это выражение в современном языке вообще редко применяется? (Лучше на часы переходить). Кроме того, разговорность и частотность - разные вещи. Мы тоже чаще говорим: полчаса (разг.) не хватило.